# Rasiowa-Sikorski Lemma

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, forcing

I am aware that $MA(\kappa)$ when $\kappa = 2^{\omega_0}$ is false, so please excuse me if this question is absolutely trivial, however I am an absolute beginner when it comes to these topics.

My question is : Where exactly *the* proof of Rasiowa-Sikorski Lemma fails to be extended to any $\kappa > \omega_0$ ?

To be more precise, I'll state the argument of such proof :
Let $D=\lbrace D_n\rbrace_{n\in\omega}$ be a collection of dense subsets of ($\mathbb{P}$,$\leq$), a partially ordered set. Choose $d_1\in D_1$ and since $D_2$ is dense, there is some $d_2\in D_2$ such that $d_2\leq d_1$. By simple induction, we get a totally ordered subset of $\mathbb{P}$ - $\lbrace d_n\rbrace_{n\in\omega}$ - such that each $d_n\in D_n$. Then, take $\mathcal{F}$ to be the filter in $\mathbb{P}$ generated by $\mathcal{F}$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}=\lbrace q\in\mathbb{P}:\exists n\in\omega : d_n\leq q\rbrace$. Then, $\mathcal{F}\cap D_n\neq\emptyset$ for each $n\in\omega$.

**My question is** : using transfinite induction, can't we choose one element $d_\alpha\in D_\alpha$ such that $d_\beta\leq d_\alpha$ for any $\beta\leq\alpha$, for any collection $\lbrace D_{\alpha}\rbrace_{\alpha\leq\kappa}$ of dense subsets of $\mathbb{P}$ ? If so, why can't we just take the filter generated by $\lbrace d_{\alpha}\rbrace_{\alpha\leq\kappa}$?

Thanks for all clarifications and excuse me, once again, if this is absolutely trivial.

Comment: There may fail to exist $d_{\omega}$ such that $d_{\omega}\leq d_n$ for all $n\in \omega.$ That is, $\mathbb P$ may fail to be countably closed. If $\mathbb P$ is not empty, and c.c.c. (every anti-chain is countable) and separative (every $x\in \mathbb P$ has two incompatible extensions)  then $\mathbb P$ can't be countably closed. Else it contains  an upside-down copy $T$ of the complete binary tree of height $\omega.$  But then a set of lower bounds for all the maximal chains of $T$ (maximal in $T,$ that is), is an uncountable anti-chain in $\mathbb P.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the Cohen forcing. Or simply the infinite binary tree. Now suppose the you take $D_n$ to be the tail segment of the tree of all levels above the $n$th one (the rest of the enumeration doesn't matter). Start making these choices of $d_n\in D_n$.

What would be $d_\omega$? It would be an element in the full binary tree, such that for every $n$, there is some $d_n\in D_n$ such that $d_\omega$ extends $d_n$. But this is impossible, since the intersection of the $D_n$'s is empty. You cannot just argue like this.

In simpler, forcing terms, you're assuming that $\Bbb P$ is $\leq\kappa$-closed. Which certainly doesn't have to be the case.

Comment: Thanks Asaf. So we can say that $MA(\kappa)$ is true for $(\mathbb{P},\leq)$ posets, with $\leq$, $\kappa$-closed. Any interesting examples of elements of such class or is it too restrictive to be interesting ?

Comment: Well, sure, collapsing $\kappa^{++}$ to $\kappa^+$ is $\leq\kappa$-closed. Or any sufficiently large collapse like that. So yeah, there are interesting examples of sufficiently closed posets; but the issue is a sufficiently interesting *forcing axiom*. And in the case of $\sf MA(\kappa)$ for $\leq\kappa$-closed forcings, this is just not interesting because it's provable from $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: I am not familiar with the terminology you used. Indeed, I never studied _forcing_ and my set theory background is fairly poor. Any suggestion on a good starting point for, let's say, be able to understand the basics on _forcing_ ?

Comment: Well, those are just partial orders with a particular structure. Martin's Axiom is the basic of the "forcing axioms". It is usually applied only to forcings which satisfy ccc, and if generalized then this is denoted in an explicit way to point out that we care about partial orders with certain properties. Generally, we say that a partial order is $\leq\kappa$-closed if every decreasing sequence of length $\leq\kappa$ has a lower bound. We say that a poset satisfies ccc if every antichain (in the strong sense) is countable. I hope this helps to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, though I was referring to "collapsing $\kappa^{++}$". I don't know what that means. But I will look for it :)

Comment: All the bounded functions from $\kappa^+$ to $\kappa^{++}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Could you define precisely $D_n$ please? (I do not understand what a tail segment is). What is $D_2$ for example? Or $D_0$?

Comment: @MadHatter: $D_n$ is all the sequences in the tree of length *at least* $n$.